# Semantic HTML tags for numbered progress bar

Tags: html, semantic-markup

What would the most relevant HTML tags be for a numbered progress bar such as:

(1) Step 1: do something
(2) Step 2: do something else
(3) Step 3: complete

I considered using an `<ol>` but in this case, the '1', '2', '3', will need styling.

[image: 1: Do something, 2: Do something else, 3: complete]

Also to indicate which step the user is currently on.

Comment: what's the harm in styling the '1', '2', '3' <li> elements? Do you prefer not giving them individual classes?

Comment: `<ol>`, if its noted as list, is indeed the way to fly. If its in a list, it has significance. You could assign a label to it as well if you dont want to go for list items. And just create a class you will assign to the list item, and you re done.

Comment: i was thinking something like: <ol><li><span>1</span> <span>do something</span></li></ol>. Just wondered if there was something better.

Comment: That sounds about right. Maybe use <h1> tags for the numbers and <p> for the text, it will maybe cost you fewer lines in the css

Answer (score 1):

As you've already decided, an ordered list is the most semantic way to show a progress bar. Unfortunately there isn't a specific HTML element or attribute for "current step" or anything similar (I wish I knew why!). So you'll need to make something yourself. The simplest way I've used before is to use an image of the step number with an alt attribute, e.g.

```
<li><img src='step1.png' alt='Step 1: Current step'>Do something</li>
```

But you could use visually-hidden text instead. The image would need to be visually distinct from the other steps so that colour-blind users are informed as well.

Comment: shame the number in the <li> isn't style-able :-(

Comment: Yeah, it's another odd thing about CSS to add to the list :(

Answer (score 1):

Probably nothing more semantic currently than:

```
<ol>
 <li class='currentStep'>
  <span>1</span> 
  <span>do something</span>
 </li>
 <li>
  <span>2</span>
  <span>do something else</span>
 </li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 0):

Semantically I agree with the use of `ol` but I believe you can achieve the desired effect with a bit of css and use of `data-attributes`

The markup would look something like this

```
<ul>
 <li data-step="1">Do something</li>
</ul>
```

Here's a sample of the implementation: http://jsbin.com/gifisireku/edit?html,css,output

The benefit of using this is you can have clean and accessible markup which is great for SEO as well ;)